# Making the colums align properly in shell script

Tags: shell, awk

i got this line of code below i wish to do it so that the output will become aligned. i am unsure of how to edit the code an example of what is in the txt file is

```
The Hunger Games:Suzanne Collins:1:1:1:1
```

i wish for it to show

```
Title             Author           Price  Qty Available  Qty Sold  Total Sales   
The Hunger Games  Suzanne Collins  1      1              1         1
```

hope someone can help me with this thanks.

```
echo -e "Title Author Price Qty Avail Qty Sold Total Sales" 
awk -F ':' -v OFS=':' '{print $1 , $2 ,"$"$3 , $4 , $5 , $6 }' BookDB.txt | column -s ':' -t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(echo "Title:Author:Price:Qty Avail:Qty Sold:Total Sales" &&
 cat BookDB.txt) | column -s: -t
```